# Queue function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, jquery-deferred

In my fiddle I have following function that is called trice (to simulate the user starting it three times in quick succession)

https://jsfiddle.net/tvs1zdw9/1/

```
function test(){
  var r = $.Deferred();

  //simulate ajax call that loads data and takes 2 seconds
  setTimeout(function(){
    r.resolve();
    count++;
    $('#here>i').html(count);
  },2000);

  return r;
}
```

**Goal:** No matter how quickly the user keeps pressing the button I always want to wait until the function completes until it is run again.

I have already added a deferrer (r) which gives an indication to when the function is done with following code:

```
test().done(function(){
    console.log('done running function');
});
```

**Example:**

- User clicks button 3 times in rapid succession
- Function is called three times (quicker than it can complete)
- There is a "Queue" that is created
- The next item in the "Queue" is kicked off whenever the function completes and not before

I found the jQuery queue functionality but it seems it is only for functions chained to items in the DOM ...perhaps I do not understand it fully. Here: https://api.jquery.com/queue/

Can anyone help me build up a queue and then go through it after each function has completed?

Comment: All of them, If I run the function 3 times it should run three times, but synchronous. So it should wait until the previous time has run through

Comment: thanks Arun, but that just "disables" the function until it has completed. I want there to be a queue

Comment: Why not use .queue(), but attach it to a .click() event on an empty div? Then you place your function inside the .click() and run it like the Jquery API shows.

Comment: Thanks Cruiser. I don't see how to pull that off. I have now found a solution, will post in a few.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be very simple, even elegant, if you implement :

- the queue as a promise chain
- the things to be queued as functions.

First, a reusable function that forms a private queue and returns a function by which items may be added to the queue.

```
function AsyncQueue(stopOnError) {
    var p = $.when(); // a resolved promise, which acts as the seed of a .then() chain (ie a "queue").
    return function(fn) {
        p = p
          .then(null, function() { if(!stopOnError) return $.when(); }) // prevent propagation of a previous error down the chain.
          .then(fn);
        return p;
    }
}
```

With this, the queue (the promise chain) will "self-administer" so the need for `running` and `runQueue()` disappears.

Now you can write :

```
function goodDelay() { // simulate a successful request
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd){ setTimeout(dfrd.resolve, 1000); });
}
function badDelay() { // simulate a failed request
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd){ setTimeout(dfrd.reject, 1000); });
}

var queue = AsyncQueue(false); // `queue` is a function with its own private .then chain.
queue(goodDelay).then(successHandler, errorHandler);
queue(badDelay).then(successHandler, errorHandler);
queue(goodDelay).then(successHandler, errorHandler);

function successHandler() {
    console.log('success:');
}
function errorHandler() {
    console.log('error:');
}
```

`stopOnError` works as follows :

- **false**: the internal error handler ensures that the queue always goes down the succcess path regardless of the previous outcome.
- **true**: the internal error handler is rendered ineffective and the queue adopts its natural (jQuery) behaviour of propagating the error down the chain. Following an error, further queued functions will not fire, though their external errorHandlers (if present) will fire and will all be informed of the same "reason" for failure.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c203ckj5/2/)** with `stopOnError` false
**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c203ckj5/1/)** with `stopOnError` true

Answer (score 0):

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/jqqmrv4L/1/

I have created a variable queue

```
var queue = [];
```

When the function is called before it is completed I will push to queue.

```
  var count = 0;
  var running = false;
  var queue = [];
    var test = function(){
    var r = $.Deferred();

    if(!running){
      running = true;

      //simulate ajax call that loads data and takes 2 seconds
      setTimeout(function(){
        r.resolve();
        count++;
        $('#here>i').html(count);
        running = false;
      },2000);
    } else {
        console.log('called whilst running');
      queue.push('234');
    }

    return r;
    }
```

Then I have another function to handle the queue which is called after the initial function has completed like so:

```
test().done(function(){
        console.log('done running function, checking queue');
      runqueue();
    });
```

And here the final "runqueue" function that handles the queue:

```
function runqueue(){
         if(queue.length){
            console.log('queue has!', queue.length);
        //runqueue();
        test().done(function(){
            console.log('queue item completed');
          queue.splice(0,1); //delete this because it has ran
          //runqueue();
        });
      } else {
        console.log('queue done');
      }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution :
(1) relies on an invariant, hard-coded `test()`,
(2) doesn't correctly reflect the usage case in the question (user clicks a button several times in rapid succession),
(3) doesn't demonstrate error handling.

Comment: 1 hard-coded test() - that is the function that is called when the button is pressed

Comment: 2 the user input is simulated by $('#userclick').trigger('click'); which is called three times in rapid succession

Comment: 3 correct there is no error handling, my real life through which i earn money is absorbing the time i would have invested in proper error handling, my bad